# Weird FTP issue between Unity Express and Windows Server 2008 FTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

My VOIP specialist complained about not being able to run backups of the Unity Express onto our FTP server (Microsoft FTP on Server 2008). I did a packet trace and observed some weird behavior that I think is even kind of funny in a way.

The Unity FTP client is able to initiate both control and data connections with no problem, even being able to `LIST` directories and `CWD` into them. But as soon as the client sends a `SYST` command (not sure why it cares), the server replies with "Windows_NT" and lo and behold...the client immediately sends a `QUIT` command! I've seen this happen consistently on my packet captures.

I tried pointing the Unity FTP client to a FileZilla FTP server, and viola...it worked fine!

Has anyone else observed this? I thought it was kinda funny, being that Cisco seems to not like Microsoft that much...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the new OOB FTP 7.5 or the one you see in Web Server Roles in Windows Server 2008? 
Also, make sure you have Unix directory listings enabled for your FTP site.

I would like to see FTP logfile and check for the status codes for the SYST request.